# How to set the properties on a dxcombobox?

Tags: combobox, blazor, devexpress

I am using dxcombobox which a DevExpress ComboBox for Blazor. I want my dropdown to be autocompleted when a user inputs a letter. Is there a way to edit the properties in dxcombobox? There are many ways to change the properties of the combobox, however, I could not find a way to change the dxcombobox.

Does dxcombobox have a autocomplete property?

Comment: Uhhh, that combobox covered on that website is a WinForms control.  That's about as far away from Blazor as you can get.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for Devexpress WinForms control:

```
ComboBox.Properties.AutoComplete = True
```